# Is it legal to write ptr = &i; in C?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, malloc, c11

I have compiled following code on GCC using `gcc prog.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11` command. It's does not generate any warning or error.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int i = 10;
    int *ptr = malloc(1);

    ptr = &i; // is it legal?

    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Displayed output of `10`.

Here, dynamic memory allocated for `ptr` pointer using `malloc` function, Then `ptr` hold the address of `i` varable.

Would it be legal to write `ptr = &i;` in C?

**Edit:**

So, Is it possible to compiler generate warning about a memory leak?

Comment: legal. And a memory leak.

Comment: notice that using the pointer without doing that is a problem here, `malloc(1)` generally is not big enough to hold an `int`

Comment: As a note, `malloc(1)` probably isn't big enough for an `int`, `malloc(sizeof(int))` would be better. In this instance it doesn't matter though (and you leak less memory!)

Comment: In c you allocate dynamic memory using malloc() and free it using free(). I just wonder how you got 10k reputation. Hope it’s not troll question.

Comment: may I ask what provokes the thought that it would be illegal?

Comment: Also, I wonder why you did not ask about `int *ptr = malloc(1);` (or wrote it, in first place), that's a gross misuse. Just my two cents.

Comment: Yeah - you bought a new toaster and threw it in the garbage straightaway.  Not illegal, but...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's nothing illegal. It's just creating a memory leak. You will never get to use that allocated memory in this instance of the program.

What you could have done possibly?

- Not allocate memory at all if it was not needed.
- You could have stored that address.
- Before overwriting what is stored in pointer, you can free that memory.

  ```
  int i = 10;
  int *ptr = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
  int *stored;
  if(ptr == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr,"Error in Malloc");
      exit(1);
  }
  stored = ptr; // avoiding memory leak.
  ptr = &i;  
  free(stored);
  printf("%d\n", *ptr);
  return 0;
  ```